# C++ socket windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I have question.
I create socket , connect , send bytes , all is ok.

and for receiving data i  use recv function.

```
char * TOReceive= new char[200];

recv(ConnectSocket, TOReceive , 200, 0);
```

when there are some data it reads and retuns, succefull , and when no data waits for data,  all i need to *limit waiting time*, for example if  10 seconds no data it should return.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows sockets has the `select` function. You pass it the socket handle and a socket to check for readability, and a timeout, and it returns telling whether the socket became readable or whether the timeout was reached.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141(VS.85).aspx

Here's how to do it:

```
bool readyToReceive(int sock, int interval = 1)
{
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(sock, &fds);

    timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = interval;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    return (select(sock + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &tv) == 1);
}
```

If it returns true, your next call to `recv` should return immediately with some data.

You could make this more robust by checking `select` for error return values and throwing exceptions in those cases. Here I just return `true` if it says one handle is ready to read, but that means I return `false` under all other circumstances, including the socket being already closed.

Comment: Thanks

 please one small example , 
select(...);
after that  recv ??

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but I prefer `WSAEventSelect` and `WaitForSingleObject` over `select`.  Just as I prefer `poll` on Unix.  `select` is just old and weird looking.  Every time I hear someone advocate it a part of me dies.

Comment: Weird... what do you do with the dead parts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `select` function prior to calling `recv` to know if there is something to be read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SO_RCVTIMEO socket option to specify the timeout value for recv() call.